# Multivariable Calculus Volume Generation

Tags: calculus

I am currently faced with this question and I am kinda confused -

Let a denote a positive constant. It is known that the volume of the solid bounded on the bottom by the surface $z = x^2 + ay^2 $  and the top by the surface $ z = (a+1)^3 - ax^2 - y^2 $ is equal to 2017π. Find the value of a.

I know that we have to use double integration by using the equation $ z = (a+1)^3 - ax^2 - y^2 $, since the volume is lying below it. However, what will be the domain that I'll need to use for integration?

Answer (score 0):

The domain will also be a function of $a$. Setting the $z$ of the two equations equal and playing around, we get $$y = \pm\sqrt{(1+a)^2-x^2}\,$$
so that'll be your bounds for $y$. Then letting $y = 0$, we'll get bounds on $x$ as $$\pm(1+a)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood.

Answer (score 0):

The two surfaces cross each other when

$$x^2+ay^2=(a+1)^3-ax^2-y^2$$
or $$x^2(1+a)+y^2(1+a)=(1+a)^3.$$

Dividing by $1+a$ we get the equation of a circle:

$$x^2+y^2=(1+a)^2.$$
The disk surrounded by this circle is the domain of integration.